# C++ Use vector rvalue as an argument

Tags: c++, vector, arguments

Consider the code snippet below:

```
void PrintLines(vector<string>& lines){}

vector<string> lines = {"Images", "Transcriptions"};
PrintLines(lines);
```

Is there a possibility to pass the lines values directly, without initializing the "lines" variable?

Like this:

```
PrintLines({"Images", "Transcriptions"});
```

Comment: That's not a code snippet. That's a syntax error.

Comment: Use `const std::vector<std::string>&`.

Comment: You should always be careful to maintain const-correctness. If a function receives an object by reference, and that function has no intention of modifying the object, then the reference should (almost) always be const.

Comment: *Consider the code snippet below:* -- It isn't that difficult to simply complete the [mcve], like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/97Yvx9as9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you've not specified the return type of the function when defining it.

> Is there a possibility to pass the lines values directly, without initializing the "lines" variable?

Yes, you can do that by making the parameter `lines` to be a *const lvalue reference to `std::vector`* so that it can bind to rvalue as shown below:

```
//              vvvvv                                      added low level const here
void PrintLines(const std::vector<std::string>& lines)
^^^^                                                    // added void as return type here                                               
{

    for(const std::string&elem: lines)
    {
        std::cout<<elem<<std::endl;
    }
}



int main()
{
    PrintLines({"Images", "Transcriptions"});//calls PrintLines
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/gt5Z4YKKx)

Comment: I think the little markers and comments unnecessarily obscure the code. Better to just remove them, add some whitespace in your loop and be done with it. Clear, concise code is more readable than code annotated with clutter. It's obvious what the changes are.

Comment: @paddy I've removed the markers and instead used whitespaces as you suggested. Though i think that it is subjective whether markers look good or not, but i agree that in this code example they don't. So i've added your suggestion in my answer by removing the markers.

Comment: Not [what I meant](https://godbolt.org/z/Pns73sEar), but okay.